# gfortran - Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a fortran code using gfortran, it is giving me an error stating

```
2.6/cp2k/tools/build_libsmm/run_tiny_dnn/output_linux.gnu/"//trim(filename)
                                                                       1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

I am not sure what could have triggered this. BTW, there was no issue with ifort and the line that triggered is

```
open(unit=unit,file=\"`pwd -P`/$(OUTDIR)/\"//trim(filename))
```

It would be great, if someone has any pointers to fix this issue.

Comment: Why did you escape `\"`???

Comment: It would help if you quoted the entire text of the error message and of the problematic line the compiler complains about.  Does it really begin `2.6/cp2k` ?

Comment: Are you trying to mix shell script with Fortran? That is bound to fail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open() statement in fortran needs the relative path to the file to open from the position of where the compiled fortran program will resort. So your code should look similar to this with `dir` the relative path to your output files.

```
! parameter declaration
integer,intent(in)::unit
char(len=512),intent(in)::dir,filename
char(len=512)::relPath
! -----------------------------------------------------------------------
relPath=trim(dir)//'/'//trim(filename)
open(unit=unit,file=trim(relPath),action='readwrite',possition='append')
```

I always add the action and position to the open command to make sure that you do the right things with your files.